# How can I serialize awaitable tasks in FIFO order

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await

In my WinRT app, the UI allows the user to click on a list item to begin downloading a preview from the server. When a list item is in this downloading state, a progress bar displays in the list item template. Thus, the UI isn't blocked, and the user is free to click on other items and start (concurrent) downloads on those as well.

When a download fails (due to network connectivity, let's say), it sends a message to the UI. The UI handles this message by displaying a MessageDialog:

```
public async void ShowError(string message)
{
    var dialog = new MessageDialog(message, "Error")
    {
        CancelCommandIndex = 0,
        DefaultCommandIndex = 0,
        Options = MessageDialogOptions.None
    };
    dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));

    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

The problem is, if the UI tries to display another message before the user has dismissed the first, the call to `MessageDialog.ShowAsync` throws `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`.

What I want to do is serialize access to this so that the second message awaits the first, then displays. A third message would await the second, and so on.

All of this is happening on the UI thread, and I'm not sure how to do this properly. Seems like I want each new error message box request to set itself up as the 'current' request, and then await the dismissal of the 'previous' one:

```
public async void ShowError(string message)
{
    ...

    // *** PSEUDO CODE FOLLOWS ***

    // If a message is being displayed...
    if (_currentTask != null)
    {
        // ...wait for that task to complete
        _currentTask = NewTaskThatWaitsFor(_currentTask);
        await _currentTask;
    }
    _currentTask = dialog.ShowAsync();
    await currentTask;
}
```

How can I 'attach' myself to await (not block--this is the UI thread) on another (UI thread) task that I previously awaited?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want to do is serialize access to this

The easiest solution is a `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _dialogMutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
public async void ShowError(string message)
{
    await _dialogMutex.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        var dialog = new MessageDialog(message, "Error")
        {
            CancelCommandIndex = 0,
            DefaultCommandIndex = 0,
            Options = MessageDialogOptions.None
        };
        dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));

        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
    finally
    {
        _dialogMutex.Release();
    }
}
```

However, since I'm already writing this up, I suggest you rethink this part:

> When a download fails (due to network connectivity, let's say), it sends a message to the UI. The UI handles this message...

I find that the code is much cleaner if you have your background tasks completely unaware of the UI. If you're using a message bus, that's fine (though I've never worked on a UI app that required a message bus); but what you want to avoid is background tasks sending messages directly to the UI.

Comment: The way it's structured is that there is an awaitable method in the ViewModel that downloads the preview for the selected list item. Since that method is async, the UI thread returns immediately, allowing the user to select other list items and start concurrent downloads. When a given download fails (caught exception), we send a message from the view model that the view subscribes to. The View handles this method by presenting the error message dialog.

Comment: This looks good, but it didn't quite work in practice for me. The result was ... weird ..., but it was sort of like the UI stopped updating as soon as the second message box would have popped up. Stopped updating, but was still responsive to clicks. Must be some plumbing thing with async/await that I don't understand.